# Detecting the last Iteration in a loop

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have a word and I want to split each character from a word.  I use FOR IN loop to split the characters. During split I want to detect first and last characters.  I use a variable count and count is initialized to 0. If count=1 then it is first character.  But similarly how can I detect the last character in FOR IN loop in python

```
    count=0;
    for w in word:
        count++
        if count==1:
            #first character
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use `enumerate`? It's meant for this very purpose.

```
for i, w in enumerate(word):
    if i in {0, len(word)-1}:
        ... # do something
```

You can get rid of the `count` variable now.

Comment: Why not use `if i == len(word)-1` ?

Comment: @Florent They want to detect both the first and last character.

Answer (score 2):

```
if count == len(word):
   #last
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the first and last characters, you can use the first and last index.

```
s = 'word'
s[0] >>> 'w'
s[-1] >>> 'd'
```

Comment: Not a good idea. You'd break early if that last char exists elsewhere.